# UnmarshalException: Method not found Exception in EJB

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb

I have added a method to my stateless sessionBean (getFNEdetails) with one String parameter.

But I am getting this error when I try to test in weblogic10 server

**java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Could not unmarshal method ID; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Method not found: 'getFNEdetails(ILjava.lang.String;)**

Any one can help me out here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more precisely what you did? Did you add the method to local and remote interface? Where the client and ejb module correctly redeployed?

Answer (score 5):

I got solution for this after my 3 hr worst time... its a deployment come build problem... Solution is Delete all the build files and rebuild all the files... it should be work fine...
Thanks for me!!!